# divide two ints and make it divisible by 50

Tags: java

let's say with have two ints; 500 and 3. If I divide the ints I will get an odd (odd as in strange) number. I want to get 150 instead of 166, making it divisible by 50 and close enough to the real divided number

Comment: ...what exactly makes you think (500/3) = 150 ?

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: `(((a / b) + 25) / 50) * 50`, if you want to round to the nearest 50, and `a/b` is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = 500;
int y = 3;
int result = (x/y) - ((x/y)%50)
```